# GET net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when loading images to SPA using ajax and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, server, single-page-application

Trying to create a single page app. The first half of my code works (reloading shows images).

BUT when submitting the form I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.
I can't understand what I'm doing wrong? Currently I have the nested ajax call because otherwise the image trys to upload before it is submitted to the json file.

My AJAX client side code::

```
$("document").ready(function(event){ 
  //event.preventDefault()
  $.ajax({
    url: "images.json",
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "JSON",
    error: function(){
      $("#status").html("<p> An error occured </p>");
    },
    success:
      function(data){
        var $image = $('#new-image')
        $.getJSON("images.json", function(data){
              $image.html("");
            for (var i = data.length; i--;)
            {
              console.log(data[i]["name"])
              $image.append('<img src="' + data[i]["name"] + '">');
            }
      })
    }
  })
})

$('form').on("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault() 
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value)
  formData.append('avatar', document.getElementById('avatar').files[0]) 

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "upload",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      data: formData,
      processData: false, 
      contentType: false, 
      cache: false,
      error: 
        function(){
          $("#status").html("<p> An error occured </p>");
        },
      success:
        function(formData){
          console.log("success")
          $.ajax({
            url: "images.json",
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "JSON",
            timeout: 4000,
            error: 
              function(){
              $("#status").html("<p> An error occured </p>");
            },
            success:
              function(data){
                var $image = $('#new-image')
                $image.html("");
                for (var i = data.length; i--;)
                {
                  console.log(data["name"])
                  $image.append('<img src="' + data[i]["name"] + '">');
                }
              }
          })
        }
      })
})
```

In case it's helpfule, my server side:

```
//npm modules
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const sharp = require('sharp');
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');
const cors = require("cors");

// Set The Storage Engine
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, './client/images');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
  });


//create server
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(express.static("./client/webpage.js"))
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));

var images = require("./client/images.json");

// Multer single file parser
const upload = multer({limits:{fileSize:4000000}}).single('avatar')
app.post('/upload', (req, res)=>{
    upload(req, res, async function(err){ 
     // check for error thrown by multer- file size etc
     if( err|| req.file === undefined){
         console.log(err)
         res.send("error occured")
     }else{
        var image = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
            .resize({ width: 200, height:200 }) 
            .toFile('./client/'+req.file.originalname)
            .catch( err => { console.log('error: ', err) })
        res.send(req.body)
        const newImage = {
          id: uuidv4(),
          name: req.file.originalname
        };
        images.push(newImage);
        const json = JSON.stringify(images);
        fs.writeFile('./client/images.json', json, 'utf8', console.log);
            }
          })
    })


//tell server which port
app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on localhost')
  });
```

Please help. Spent so long on trying to fix this and I'm about ready to give up.

html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> FIRST SPA PAGE </a>
          <div class="search">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
              <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-box" placeholder="Search" >
                <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" >Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

      <div id="wrapper">
        <img src="mountains.jpg" id="coverphoto" alt="cover photo">
          <div class="centered">WELCOME.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
          Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/> <br/>
          Image: <input type="file"  name="image" id="avatar"/><br/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <div id="status">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id=new-image>
      </div>
    <script src="webpage.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

file:

-APP

--server.js

--client

---webpage.js

---index.js

---images.json

APP is main folder.

server.js and client folder inside APP.

webpage.js, index.js and images.js inside client.

Comment: I reproduced your code(i don't have it all, so worked with you provide), and it works 100%. There is probably something missing here. Can you debug the issue and provide maybe more details?

Comment: If I'm lucky the first and maybe second image uploads work and then the subsequent uploads show a blank box and an error. If I reload the page all the images show fine, it's just on uploading. I have screenshot examples of what it's showing. https://imgur.com/gallery/m3VFHRb They are all GET errors.Also, once the image is saved (in folder and json file) if that image is uploaded again it works fine. If the image is not already saved, and it's being uploaded for the first time then errors occur.

Comment: You didn't say that the error occurs when fetching the actual images...i thought you're getting the error in your AJAX... Please provide your html that fetches the images

Comment: Well i see you're also getting this error with your images.json...i trully don't know why it's happening..It's probably something that is related to Linux or networking

Comment: I edited the above with the html and file structure.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the networking. Don't think it is linux but i will check that too.